# Use a do while loop to access menu

Tags: c++, loops, do-while

I need to write a program to only allow customers who know the username/password access a food menu.  I have to use a do while loop.  Here is my code but because of the do while loop the menu will appear   even though the username/password is wrong which shouldn't happen.

```
 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    string sUserName = "";
    string sPassword = "";

    cout <<"Username: ";
    cin >> sUserName;
    cout <<"Password: ";
    cin >> sPassword;

    do
    {
        //order from a menu

    }
        while(sUserName == "wiseguy" && sPassword == "opensesame");

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: try a simple `while` loop then.

Comment: Are you sure you have to use the do/while for ordering the menu? Maybe the idea is to use do/while to enter username/password until it is correct

Comment: You might be right.  Not sure how I would do that.

Comment: Well, thats the idea behind an assignment. Figure out how to do it, and learn how to program :) As tipp: run the loop as long as the inputs are NOT correct

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Think I figured it out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should try something a bit different.

The do while loop should check for a username and prompt again if the username and password was incorrect.

```
do
{
    cout <<"Username: ";
    cin >> sUserName;
    cout <<"Password: ";
    cin >> sPassword;

} while(sUserName != "wiseguy" || sPassword != "opensesame");

// order from menu
```

Comment: while(sUserName != "wiseguy" && sPassword != "opensesame");

Comment: It must be `||`, not `&&`

Answer (score 0):

The `do..while` loop **will** execute at least one time even if the condition in the `while(...);` is false. After execution of the body of the loop, the condition will be checked. So I think that it is better if you use `while` loop instead of `do...while` as `while` loop checks the condition first before executing its body.